# How to use variable (state) in URL string in React?

Tags: reactjs, variables, url, request, axios

here's my [source code](https://github.com/pedro-surf/ufsc_exercises/blob/master/App.js)

The problem is in fact with these GET requests

```
    getModels = async () => {
    if (this.state.query_brand !== 0) {
         this.setState({ loading: "Fetching models..." });
         let brand = Number(this.state.query_brand);
         let targetURL = 
'https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas/${brand}' + '/modelos/';  
           await axios.get(`${targetURL}`)
                    .then(res => this.setState({ models: res.data }))
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}};
```

Thanks!! I solved it with this:

```
 let targetURL =
        "https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas/" +
        brand +
        "/modelos/" +
        model +
        "/anos";
      console.log(targetURL);
      await axios
        .get(`${targetURL}`)...promises
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem here:

```
let targetURL = 'https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas/${brand}' + '/modelos/';
```

the `${brand}` in this line is pure string with value = **${brand}**, not the value of `brand`. You should use template literal in this line

```
let targetURL = `https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas/${brand}/modelos/`;
```